# What is the standart for "params" in EIP-1193 (Ethereum Provider JS API)?

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, signature, eip

I am trying to build some low-level provider stuff and I am wondering what I should sign when I try to implement personal_signMessage and eth_sign.

Basically, every windows.ethereum.request() has a method and a params object. When the method is `sendTransaction` it is very clear what the params are. They are `to`, `from`, `data` and so on. But when the method is `eth_sign`, `personal_sign`, `eth_signTypedData` what should be signed from the params object?
Most of the times it's just an array with string like `0x123` or something.

Is there a standart for what should be signed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the relevant docs [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/) and [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712)

In regards to `eth_sign` and `eth_signTypedData`, which were implemented in **EIP712**, these params are `address` and `typedData` where the latter is a JSON object, the schema for which can be seen in the docs linked above.

You can follow these docs to see what the params are in order to architect your implementation.

For `personal_sign`, for example, it requires you use `web3.toHex` in encoding your function's param:

```
web3.personal.sign(web3.toHex("signing message goes here"), <FROM-ADDRESS>, function(err, 
signature) {
      console.log(signature);
}
```